# Pure-Javascript MVC-framework

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, web-applications, frameworks, single-page-application

I recently made use of Backbone as the **MVC-framework** for the **single page web application** we developed in my company. I found out that Backbone lacks some features that are quite important for larger applications (**e.g. ui bindings, module-concept as in CommmonJS**) poor model-definitions).

During my research on JavaScript-MVC-frameworks that would fill those gaps I only found frameworks requiring **additional server software, compiling** and so on.

Aren't there any pure-JS-MVC-frameworks?

Thanks in advance :)

Best wishes

Leo

Comment: Every web application needs some serverside software? Or do you look for MVC frameworks where also the serverside part is written in JS?

Comment: Of course they do, but I also found a framework requiring certain scripts on the server

Comment: For example, Backbone does not require special server softwae (only the requests and responses must be JSON)

Comment: Take a look at angularjs for a good MVC framework. Also there's knockoutJS for an MVVM approach. Although knockout doesn't include its own templating system IIRC.

Comment: I really liked AngualarJS but it requires compilation :/
Thanks, I will read through :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As far as modules are concerned:

You could introduce modules to a Backbone-based application fairly simply. I would recommend AMD over CommonJS (using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)) as the module pattern to use.  You have the option to build a "build" system for it, but don't need to.

Something like the following could be the situation:

- Models in `js/myapp/models/`
- Views in `js/myapp/views/`
- etc..

Where each model/view is wrapped in a call to RequireJS's `define()` function.

Inside of your main script, you could require the views/models using RequireJS's `require()` function.

#### UI Bindings:

Using Backbone by itself: they're not necessarily "bindings", but you can listen to model change events in your views and update the spots in your views where the model values are displayed.

Using a plugin, like [backbone.modelBinding](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding) you can get closer to real binding.